# Cannot consume content type - even with correct @Consumes

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

I'm working on a REST resource that takes in a key and data (value) . I'd like to be robust so this data can be anything. It could range from a string to a file.

To handle this, I have the PUT REST method which is at the end of the post. Nothing fancy, just trying to PUT basic data.  If I send data that is a string it works no problem.

However, if I try to send a file across, I get this error: `org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Cannot consume content type`. Here's why this doesn't make sense to me:

If I change the `@Consumes` from `application/octet-stream` to `@Consumes("multipart/form-data")`, I can send a file across just fine. When examining the file that's stored I see something like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryfuQalizBHtg1BiLJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileUpload1"; filename="uploadedFile.extension"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

/* file information here */
------WebKitFormBoundaryfuQalizBHtg1BiLJ--
```

Notice that the `Content-Type` is supposedly `application/octet-stream` which is what I tried consuming before but got the `Cannot consume content type` exception. I have no idea what would be causing this.  I'm using the Advanced Rest Client extension for Chrome to send my request and it looks something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWAQk.jpg

Any thoughts?

```
@PUT
@Path("{key}")
@Consumes("application/octet-stream")
public Response addData(
    final @PathParam("key") String key,
    final InputStream data) {
  final Service service =  new Service();
  try {
    service.addData(key, data);
  } finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(data
  }
  return Response.status(204).build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `multipart/form-data` message contains a series of parts divided by a boundary. Every part has its own Content-Type. So in your example `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` is the Content-Type of one (and probably the only one) part but the Content-Type of the whole message is `multipart/form-data`. A full message with multiple parts could look like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=WebKitFormBoundaryfuQalizBHtg1BiLJ

------WebKitFormBoundaryfuQalizBHtg1BiLJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileUpload1"; filename="uploadedFile.extension"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

/* file information here */
------WebKitFormBoundaryfuQalizBHtg1BiLJ--

------WebKitFormBoundaryfuQalizBHtg1BiLJ
Content-Type: text/plain 

/* some text here */
------WebKitFormBoundaryfuQalizBHtg1BiLJ--
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Is there any reason I can't have my `@Consumes` be `application/octet-stream`? I can't figure out why I'm getting the 'can't consume content type' exception when it should match.

Comment: It does not match. You are sending `multipart/form-data` and this should be consumed by your resource class. `application/octet-stream` is only one part.

Comment: Is it possible to send `application/octet-stream` which can also be consumed by my resource as such?

Comment: Sure! I didn't try with Advanced Rest Client but [here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12558253) using cURL.