# Post file from Command Prompt

Tags: php, batch-file, curl, cmd, wget

I am working on a batch-script that makes a SQL query and saves it to a file. The file will then be handled by PHP. Is it possible to POST a file from Windows CMD to a PHP site so it can be handled by php with `$_FILES['someFile']`?

Comment: This question should be asked on [Software Recommendations SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) or [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com) + there are already plenty of questions asking for the same: [How to download files from command line in Windows, like Wget is doing?](http://superuser.com/questions/25538/how-to-download-files-from-command-line-in-windows-like-wget-is-doing), [POST binary file with cmd line curl using headers contained in the file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053937/post-binary-file-with-cmd-line-curl-using-headers-contained-in-the-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) for this.

```
curl -F someFile=@localfile.sql http://example.org/upload
```

Comment: Great! can you make it open the site in a browser instead og inside cmd?

Comment: I sorted it out. Just '-o \path\to\file.txt' and then open it!

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use [`wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/).

```
wget --post-file=file.jpg http://yourdomain.com/target.php
```